# Few questions regarding the meaning of functions

Tags: vedas, advaita, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, smarta

Can someone tell me what are the meaning of the two below functions?

1. Rudra Ekadesi.
2. Udaga Shanthi
3. Naandhi

Can someone tell me what are the purpose of these functions?
Why and when should it be done.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a separate question for each of these as they are different topics.